# WPF Multibinding not working - Labels are blank

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, multibinding

I'm trying to bind two values into the content of one label with a space in the middle. I'm following an example from MSDN ([MSDN Article](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/La-classe-Multibinding-in-41c6816e)) but my labels are empty. Here is the code I have:

Class:

```
public class Item
{
    //Other properties removed to shorten
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string typeLine { get; set; }
}
```

Setting the items source:

```
ItemsDisplay.ItemsSource = searchResults;
```

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl Name="ItemsDisplay">
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>

             <Grid>
                 <!-- COLUMN DEFINITIONS ETC REMOVED TO SHORTEN -->

                 <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                     <Label Name="ItemName" Margin="10">
                         <Label.Content>
                             <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                                 <Binding Path="name" />
                                 <Binding Path="typeLine" />
                             </MultiBinding>
                         </Label.Content>
                     </Label>

                 </StackPanel>

             </Grid>

         </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

If I bind a single value it works perfectly E.g.

```
             <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                 <Label Name="ItemName" Margin="10" Content="{Binding Path=name}" />
                 <Label Name="ItemType" Margin="10" Content="{Binding Path=typeLine}" />
             </StackPanel>
```

So it doesn't appear to be a problem retrieving the values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot set `MultiBinding` whitout `MultiValueConverter`.

Try this:

```
<ItemsControl Name="ItemsDisplay">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <local:MyMultiConv x:Key="MyConv"/>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <!-- COLUMN DEFINITIONS ETC REMOVED TO SHORTEN -->
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                            <Label Name="ItemName" Margin="10">
                                <Label.Content>
                                    <MultiBinding  Converter="{StaticResource MyConv}">
                                        <Binding Path="name" />
                                        <Binding Path="typeLine" />
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </Label.Content>
                            </Label>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

And converter:

```
public class MyMultiConv : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", values[0], values[1]);
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

**Edit**

If you binding to directly "TextProperty" you actualy can:

```
<Textblock Name="ItemName" Margin="10">
        <Textblock.Text>
                <MultiBinding  StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                    <Binding Path="name" />
                    <Binding Path="typeLine" />
               </MultiBinding>
        </Textblock.Text>
</Textblock>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It's now telling me that 'local:MyMultiConv' was not found.

Comment: I have my MyMultiConv in WpfApp5 napesapce, so my local in xaml is: 
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp5"

Comment: I had put the converter beneath the namespace closing brace lol. Thanks that worked.

Comment: i did edit, i was in little mistake ;d there is one case when you can do this without converter :)